# What does determine if a distribution is Gaussian?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

If the probability density function is unknown, having a mean $\mu$ and a variance $\sigma^2$ doesn't mean a distribution must be Gaussian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a random variable $X$ that has a mean and variance, this doesn’t uniquely identify it’s distribution. Only certain properties. For example, if you know that the mean $\mu < \infty$ and that $\sigma^2 < \infty$ then this would imply that you don’t have a Cauchy random variable, but lots of distributions have a finite mean and variance.

If you introduce charactaristic functions into the situtation,

$$E[e^{itX}]$$

Then you can use The Uniqueness Theorem of charactaristic functions which says that if you have a charactaristic function that comes out to be

$$e^{it\mu - \frac{1}{2}t^2\sigma^2}$$

For $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\sigma \geq 0$, Then $X$ has the pdf of a $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

The more general way to say this in measure theory is if you have two Fourier transforms of probability measures (charactaristic functions) $\hat{\mu}$ and $\hat{\nu}$ and you find that $\hat{\mu}=\hat{\nu}$ then $\mu = \nu$.

Where $\mu$ and $\nu$ are two finite measures on $\mathbb{R}$, othewise known as pdfs in probability language.

So to summarize, charactaristic functions equal $\to$ pdfs equal.

NOTE: this doesn’t translate to moment generating functions, not all random variables have moment generating functions but they all have charactaristic functions.

Comment: So basically a characteristic function sets all moments of the sample set. If all moments agree with those of one particular distribution, then that's the distribution the sample set belongs to, the answer.

Comment: You're on the right track but I wouldn't think of the characteristic function and the moment generating function as the same thing. They are related, if the random variable $X$ has $k$ moments then the characteristic function is $k$ times differentiable. But the characteristic function doesn't determine the moments. Some random variables don't have a moment generating function. But for the Normal Distribution, like you said if all moments agree with a normal, then you can say that they are coming from a normal distribution.

Comment: But in general you can always rely on the Fourier Transform of the pdf, which is the definition of the characteristic function.

Comment: many thx jon :)

Comment: You’re welcome! If the answer was what you were looking for, an upvote would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: yes, i did. but it says my vote doesnt count cuz my reputation is low

Comment: Oh yeah makes sense, thank you!